# How to make UINavigationItem backBarButtonItem rectangular?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, backbarbuttonitem

How can set `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` of my `RootViewController`, so that the back button is rectangular instead of having a back arrow? I want to do this because I'm using a custom `backBarButtonItem` with an image of a grid of four squares (like the nine-square-gird image that the Facebook iPhone app uses for its home button).

Currently, in `-[RootViewController initWitNibName:bundle:]`, I do:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go-home.png"]
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:nil action:NULL];
```

*Note: This does not cause a memory leak as I'm using ARC.*

But, this makes the button have a left arrow. Is there a simple fix to make the button rectangular on all sides?

I know I could set the `leftBarButtonItem` for all of the view controllers that can get pushed from the `RootViewController`, but there are like five different options, so that'd be a lot of repetition. I guess I could make a method, e.g., `+[Utils homeBarButtonItem]`, that creates the button above and then call `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [Utils homeBarButtonItem];` in each of the five view controllers' `-viewDidLoad` methods, but I'm wondering if there's a simple fix I'm missing.

Comment: sounds like you've spent more time thinking about this than just doing it as you describe ;)  (there isn't a quicker way btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the only way, as you suggest, is to use a `leftBarButtonItem` and use a button builder utility class.

Set the action of your `leftBarButtonItem` to pop the view controller and you're done.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```